# Ways to know if connect() succeeded for Bluetooth connection

Tags: java, exception, bluetooth, ioexception

is there any way to know whether if connect() method succeeded or not?

I have the code in class ConnectThread:

```
public void run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        return;
    }
}
```

and try connecting this thread as:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) 
{
    // Loop through paired devices
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
    {
        if (device.getName().equals("HC-06"))
        {
            Thread initialThread = new ConnectThread(device);
            initialThread.run();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find out if this connection was successful or not. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it didn't succeed it will have thrown an exception. If you get to the statement after the connect() call, it succeeded.

Comment: If it throws an exception, should the program just freeze? I tried to connect with a random UUID, in which case an exception should have been thrown, but the program runs just fine with it.